# In Wordpress, can I use WP_Query with timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have code like this,

```
    $date_arg = array(
        'after' => array(
            'year'  => $num_days_ago['year'],
            'month' => $num_days_ago['mon'],
            'day'   => $num_days_ago['mday'],
    ),
        'inclusive' => false,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( array ( 'date_query' => $date_arg, 'post_type' => $post_type ...
```

This is working fine but I have to specify a exact date. Is it possible to use "timestamp" to make the query.

For example, I want to query posts that is within 24 hours. I can get the timestamp by

```
$ts = time() - DAY_IN_SECONDS
```

It is possible to get the posts that is created after $ts?

Comment: I think you have to use `meta_query` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try constructing a date using the `date()` and `strtotime()` functions.

```
$date_query = array(
    'after' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hours'))
);
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at this handy website - http://www.viper007bond.com/tag/wp_date_query/

Answer (score 0):

IMHO better like so :

```
function filter_where($where = '') { 
  $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-24 hours')) . "'"; 
  return $where; 
} 
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

and more general :

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts in the last x days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";// here 30
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); // add the filter before setting object or before loop
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); // .. and do not forget to remove it
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try something like this

```
SELECT post_title, IF (post_date_gmt < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)), 'false', 'true') AS A FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp